# Having a struct at compilation time

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I would like to have access to structure at compilation time (not a runtime) with help of macro. For example, I have a number of commands which have their own hexadecimal codes and a lenghts of response. So I need to access one or another value by one name by means of preprocessor.

Say, the command is named as READ_SOMETHING_FROM_THAT_PLACE and it has a code 0xAB and 7 responded bytes as an answer.

This research intends to avoid using of two definitions such as:

```
#define READ_SOMETHING_FROM_THAT_PLACE_CODE 0xAB
#define READ_SOMETHING_FROM_THAT_PLACE_LEN 7
```

instead it would be more convenient and robust to access to both by one instance. I guess it could be accessed by macro like (kind of):

CODE(READ_SOMETHING_FROM_THAT_PLACE) and preprocessor would give me 0xAB

LEN(READ_SOMETHING_FROM_THAT_PLACE) and preprocessor would give me 7.

Is it possible? How to do it?
Thanks.

Comment: Create a structure and get a field for each macro, but then you perhaps don't really need the macro.

Comment: Even if you don't know how to do something, posting code instead of the description of code will make your question *much* clearer.

Comment: Sounds like [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/142198).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a structure to store your commands, with 2 fields, 1 for the code and the other for the length ir returns and then you can do many things with it, even your own idea which honestly doesn't seem like a good idea, or at least not necessary.

Perhaps like this,

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define CODE(cmd) (commands[cmd].code)
#define LEN(cmd) (commands[cmd].length)

struct command {
    unsigned char code;
    int length;
};

enum {
    Read = 0
};

static const struct command commands[] = {
    [Read] = {0xAB, 0x07}
};

int
main(void)
{
    fprintf(stdout, "0x%02X, %d\n", CODE(Read), LEN(Read));
    return 0;
}
```

A good method would probable involve another structure with your commands as fields, like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct command {
    unsigned char code;
    int length;
};

struct commands {
    struct command read;
    struct command write;
    /* More commands */
};


static const struct commands table = {
    .read = {0xAB, 0x07}
};

int
main(void)
{
    fprintf(stdout, "0x%02X, %d\n", table.read.code, table.read.length);
    return 0;
}
```

You could now have a function,

```
unsigned char *execute(const struct command *const cmd);
```

and call it like<sup>1</sup>,

```
unsigned char *response = execute(&table.read);
```

you then have a generic interface for executing a command, and you don't need to worry about the actual `code` or the return length because you have access to them.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>You could also, have some parameters for every command defined in the same way.</sub>